# Unit Testing Cakephp Plugin

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Is there any possibility that I can test CakePHP plugins?

All of my core Controller and Model tests are working fine but when I try to test the controller of my plugin it gives me the error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

See my code below:

```
public function testTest() {
        $result   = $this->testAction("/MyPluginController/trst",array("return"=>"vars"));
        debug($result);
}
```

Any ideas?
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `App::uses` at the top?

`App::uses('ControllerNameController', 'MyPlugin.Controller');`